# Teradata SQL syntax error : Invalid FORMAT string 'hh:mi:ss.s(7)'

Tags: teradata

I am trying to get following teradata date format : 2020-04-14 09:10:57.0851800 (GMT-04:00).
Running query like below. It runs fine till 'hh:mi:ss.s(6)'. But gives error if i change it to 7.

> Error : Invalid FORMAT string 'hh:mi:ss.s(7)'.

Code:

```
SELECT
    ((VLUTN_START_DTM (format 'yyyy-mm-dd')) (varchar(10))) || ' ' || ((VLUTN_START_DTM (format 'hh:mi:ss.s(7)')) (varchar(27))) || ' ' || '(GMT-04:00)' (title ''),
    ((VLUTN_END_DTM (format 'yyyy-mm-dd')) (varchar(10))) || ' ' || ((VLUTN_END_DTM (format 'hh:mi:ss.s(7)')) (varchar(27))) || ' ' || '(GMT-04:00)' (title '') (title '')
FROM 
    teradatatable
```

Answer (score 0):

The column on which you are applying the format is of type Timestamp(6). The precision of the value after seconds is defined using `fractional_seconds_precision`. Here in this case it is 6. If you try to fetch any value with in the range of 1-6 it will work fine. If you try to fetch the `fractional_seconds` with a precision of up to 7 places then Teradata starts throwing an error.

You can infer the same from the [Teradata documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/S0Fw2AVH8ff3MDA0wDOHlQ/z3fHXRJXcHc_JMI737ZF9Q).

Answer (score 0):

The data types Time & Timestamp support only 6 fractional digits, thus FORMAT is limited, too.

But TO_CHAR/TO_TIMESTAMP allow up to 9 digits:

```
to_char(VLUTN_START_DTM, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi.ss.ff7 "(GMT-04:00)"')
```

Comment: True, though it seems misleading to display greater "precision" than what can actually be stored.

Comment: Great, Thank you, this is what I am looking for to compare with my source date which is of type string with 7 digit time stamp.